# Play 2.0 eclipsify command removes Scala nature

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-ide

I have added Scala nature to play project in eclipse by project->configure->add scala nature.
If I call the eclipsify command then it converts the eclipse project nature back to Java.

I am using Play Framework version 2.04. I have updated the Scala IDE to latest version 2.10, but it did not help.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `mainLang = SCALA` in your `project/Build.scala` file:

```
...
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
)
```